# How do i configure team system 2008

Tags: tfs

I am installing VSTS. What components do i need to install for both .net & sql server. ?
How do we configure our projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to a successful Team System environment: **Team Foundation Server** and **Visual Studio Team System**.

For best results, install the former on a dedicated server.  There are great resources to help you through installation [right from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181232%28VS.80%29.aspx).  There's even a [video series](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb507749.aspx) of TFS-related content!

Once your Team Foundation Server (TFS) is installed, Visual Studio Team System (VSTS) is installed on your development workstation.  VSTS looks just like any other VS install at startup.  To configure it to work with your TFS instance, go into *Tools* > *Options* and Select *Source Control*: here you will see a pull down which should contain an entry entitled *Visual Studio Team Foundation Server*.  I forget how to select your TFS server instance for VSTS to work with but I don't recall having trouble with it when I did it a few months ago.

Once you've configured all that, you interact with your TFS work items and source code from the **Team Explorer** and **Source Control Explorer** panes in VSTS: it should begin to feel rather like using VS without integrated source control from there forward.

The bigger issue is configuring your process in TFS to reflect your project's strategy, etc.  That is an exercise in thought/reading more-so than how to configure it.

All this documentation is readily available via Microsoft's website.  It does require some reading but devote some time to it: it'll pay off in the long run.

Comment: I dont know anything abt Team System. I had a team system setup of 4GB and i have installed it on my system.

now what i have to do to work in a network.

Comment: how do i know that software that i installed is Team Foundation Server or something else

Comment: @Shantanu: I've added some material in my answer.  I hope it helps.

Comment: @antik: Thx a lot for ur great help.
Now i m getting little bit idea what has to be done.
I have just installed VSTS on 1 machine and i was trying to configure my code using it.
But nyway i will try to get it,
Do u have any video tuitorial that can make me more clearer how to set up TFS nd VSTS

Comment: There's a whole series of video tutorials for TFS and VSTS here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb507749.aspx

Comment: thx a ton. will disturb u after watching these videos if left with ny more doubt
thx nyway

Answer (score 1):

[Team Foundation Server Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400732%28VS.80%29.aspx)